# Get categories in a Prestashop theme

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I'd like to get all my categories in my header (`header.tpl`) of my Prestashop theme but it seems not working well...

My code `header.tpl` :

```
{$childCategories= Category::getChildren(0, 0, $active = true, $id_shop = false);}
{printf($childCategories)}
```

Issue : Error 500

Comment: Have you checked your apache error log file ? Which version of Prestashop are you using ?

Comment: I'm using the lastest version and the error is that `Category` is not exist... But where can I send the categories to the template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you have written is not valid for smarty. Prestashop uses [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to render templates. Please, take a look to the rules if you want to avoid troubles like this. Also, you have a lot of examples in the default theme of Prestashop to learn more about coding in Smarty.

The right code would be:

```
{assign var='childCategories' value=Category::getChildren(1, 1, true, false)}
```

**Arguments to be passed**

1. $id_parent : The parent category id. The root id category is 1 and the home id category is 2.
2. $id_lang: The id language. You can check it in the localization area to get the id of a language. If you have enable multiple languages, you could use the $language variable to get the id. [List of global variables](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/57122-global-smarty-variables-used-in-prestashop/) in Prestashop.
3. $active: Return only the active caregories.
4. $id_shop: The id of a shop if you have got multiple shops in an instalation.

**Printing variables to debug**

If you want debug or see the variables, you could try the following snippets of code:

```
{* Print only the variable $childCategories *}
{$childCategories|var_dump}
```

or:

```
{* Print all variables *}
{debug}
```

Answer (score 0):

A template `header.tpl` comes from `FrontController.php` function `displayHeader()`.

`Category` doesn't exists there, because `header.tpl` is a comprehensive template used in all pages.

There are several hooks which you can use adding content there: `displayHeader`, `displayTop`, `displayLeftColumn`, `displayRightColumn`, `displayFooter`.

You can add all categories in any module and one of these hooks like that:

```
$category = new Category((int)Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY'), $this->context->language->id);
$sub_categories = $category->getSubCategories($this->context->language->id);
// else code
```

Comment: This solution is good, but i think it has got a drawback: you have to develop a module. This solution is better if you want to modify the result of the result, for example, making a custom filter of categories. But if you don't have any special feature, the simplest way to get them is through a static  call.

Comment: Yes, but developing a module is a preferred way if you want to make your system safe for a theme upgrades.